# Yii2 - What is the best way to get all unique model attribute values?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, activerecord, yii2

My model FAQ has 4 attributes

`* @property integer $id
 * @property string $chapter
 * @property string $question
 * @property string $answer`

Right now my actionIndex function looks like

```
public function actionIndex()
{

    $faq = Faq::find()->all();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Faq::find(),
    ]);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'faq' => $faq
    ]);
}
```

How can I get an array of unique values of $chapter using Yii2 or PHP in Controller? Lets say in sql it looks like

`SELECT DISTINCT chapter FROM ' faq_table'`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This can be done like this:

```
Faq::find()->select('chapter')->distinct()->all();
```

If you want the results as a plain array instead of an array containing Faq models you can add `asArray()` before `->all()`.

Running the code below will show you it'll produce this exact query.

```
Faq::find()->select('chapter')->distinct()->createCommand()->getSql();
```

---

Extra comment. I also think it's better to remove the line `$faq = Faq::find()->all();` and use `$dataProvider->getModels()` if you want to use the models. This way the query to fetch the data isn't run twice.

Comment: This query returns an array of active records. Does exists a way to return an array with the column values? `['chapter1','chapter2']`

Comment: Ok, I find the solution: `Faq::find()->select('chapter')->distinct()->asArray()->column();`